How do i delete the blue-green color on meshes? its not the material, i went in the solid tab and changed the thing to attributes

It's this color that seems to make me uncomfortable. However i cannot change it.
It is not Material by the way.

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Please don't crop out essential information from your screenshots, this hides away any details that could possibly hint at what your issue is. As it stands a partial screenshot of the subject without context or further information makes it impossible to diagnose the issue. Please edit your post and replace your images with full uncropped screenshots showing the user interface, properties, and any relevant parameters that might help us solve the issue.

I remember being very uncomfortable with that too when I was a beginner :) This is very handy tho

This is the viewport display color. Change it in Viewport Display panel either in the Object tab or Material tab in the Properties editor


